# Auditing Callbacks in Flask

Tags: flask, callback

I have a Flask application that is getting a request, sending a response, and then doing a lot of work to request some BigQuery queries be executed and then run some other job on those resulting tables.  I am using add_done_callback method of BQ Client query object so that I can move on to the next object:

```
for table in tables:
    query = create_query(table)
    Client.query(query).add_done_callback(some_callable.callback_function)
```

at the end of my code, I would like to have a set or records like

```
[
{id: 1, query_id: query_1, query_status: DONE, callback_id: callback_1, callback_status: RUNNING},
{id: 2, query_id: query_2, query_status: ERROR, callback_id: NONE, callback_status: SKIPPED},
{id: 3, query_id: NONE, query_status: SKIPPED, callback_id: NONE, callback_status: SKIPPED}
]
```

but I cannot currently find any way to wait for all of the callbacks to finish in order to have the list be precise, for instance, if query_1 takes a long time to run, by the time all of the callbacks have been executed, it might look like

```
[
{id: 2, query_id: query_2, query_status: ERROR, callback_id: NONE, callback_status: SKIPPED},
{id: 3, query_id: NONE, query_status: SKIPPED, callback_id: NONE, callback_status: SKIPPED}
]
```

Is there a good way in flask to wait for all the callbacks to complete?